# UFD test - software?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, computer-algebra-systems

I have a quotient of a polynomial ring. I would like to check if it is a UFD. Is there software that will allow me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [sagemath](http://cloud.sagemath.com):

To check if given ring is UFD, use the category UniqueFactorizationDomains()

For example:

```
   QQ in UniqueFactorizationDomains()
   True
   ZZ[sqrt(-5)] in UniqueFactorizationDomains()
   False
```

To read more about it, see [sage documents](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/categories/sage/categories/unique_factorization_domains.html), and about polynomial rings, see [this article](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour_polynomial.html)

Comment: No SageMath will give totally wrong answer. See https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/36266